# Ruby RVM under another user from Bash script

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, sudo, su

What is the best way to launch ruby script under another user via **su** command and from another script?

I have a bash script with the following command for launching unicorn:

```
sudo -u unicornuser sh -l -c "bundle exec unicorn_rails -E production -D"
```

This script is an **init.d** script and it being execute when system starts and manually also.

The problem is the default ruby on system is 1.8, other rubyes (1.9) is working under RVM. I need to modify above script that it can execute ruby with RVM (non system wide)

Now I've migrated for this notation:

```
su -l -c "rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125 && bundle exec unicorn_rails -E production -D" unicornuser
```

this worked for me, but I guess there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use wrappers:

```
rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p125 ext_1.9.3 bundle
```

This will create `$rvm_path/bin/ext_1.9.3_bundle`, so now you can use:

```
/full/path/to/rvm/bin/ext_1.9.3_bundle exec unicorn_rails -E production -D
```

replace `/full/path/to/rvm` with output from `echo $rvm_path`